# How to visualize dynamic microservice architecture running with Consul?

Tags: microservices, consul

Using Consul, you could allow your teams decentrally deploy and run microservices with dynamic dependencies.

It is also possible to list the services: `/catalog/service/:service`

Now, how to assess these dependencies automatically if the architecture grows dynamically to get a visual representation of service inter-dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you take a look at the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) library for Python.  With a script you could query Consul and build a graph of linked nodes which could be rendered to an image file and served with a web server.  A Flask microservice for this would be fairly simple to set up and provide a very useful visualization of your microservices spiderweb.

Comment: I would add that NetworkX graph operations can help you estimate your operational risk and technical debt in addition to just visualizing the dependency graph of your SOA.

Answer (score 0):

Consul is for service location; a service can use it to find another service so long as it knows the name of the service it wants to find. Consul is *not* for dependency tracking, and provides no insights into what services are using what other services (in fact it cannot, because service location does not have a way to indicate what service is doing the requesting, only what service is being requested).

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?